# How to get requested librairies of gridwars?

Tags: executable, shared-library

I would like to get a list of libraries requested by Gridwars executable.

I one year ago used ldd but

```
moi@myComputer:/opt/gridwars/gridwars_lin$ ldd gridwars 
    not a dynamic executable
```

After browsing the Internet, I found

```
moi@myComputer:/opt/gridwars/gridwars_lin$ readelf -d gridwars 

Dynamic section at offset 0x70014 contains 27 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libX11.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libGL.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libGLU.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libXxf86vm.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.5]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000c (INIT)                       0x804a284
 0x0000000d (FINI)                       0x80b29bd
 0x00000004 (HASH)                       0x8048168
 0x00000005 (STRTAB)                     0x8049268
 0x00000006 (SYMTAB)                     0x8048678
 0x0000000a (STRSZ)                      2091 (bytes)
 0x0000000b (SYMENT)                     16 (bytes)
 0x00000015 (DEBUG)                      0x0
 0x00000003 (PLTGOT)                     0x80b811c
 0x00000002 (PLTRELSZ)                   1408 (bytes)
 0x00000014 (PLTREL)                     REL
 0x00000017 (JMPREL)                     0x8049d04
 0x00000011 (REL)                        0x8049cd4
 0x00000012 (RELSZ)                      48 (bytes)
 0x00000013 (RELENT)                     8 (bytes)
 0x6ffffffe (VERNEED)                    0x8049c14
 0x6fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)                 4
 0x6ffffff0 (VERSYM)                     0x8049a94
 0x00000000 (NULL)                       0x0
```

Right I have a list of the requested shared objects.  But this still cause me some trouble : I cannot understand two things...

As proposed in comment, we may want to run file utility on the executable.

```
moi@mycomputer:/opt/gridwars/gridwars_lin$ file gridwars 
gridwars: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.0, stripped
```

- How can I check if one ".so" file/shared object is available?
- Why the hell the gridwars executable is not an executable?  I remember the thing to be a executable and even having found a magic command in three letters that list requested shared objects and if there were available.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Were the permissions on the 'gridwars executable' file set to be executable? *(If not - run `chmod +x` on it)*.

Comment: I would blame your source, I got the Gridwars 1 and only had to install a library... the file was executable...

Comment: @wilf Error on exutable bit is "bash: ./gridwars: Permission denied", not "    not a dynamic executable"

Comment: @Braiam : source are downloaded from official site whiwh does not seems to evolve...

Comment: It needs to be exuectable before you can run it  - `chmod` needs to be run with `sudo`, and so will the `./gridwars` file if it is installing anythin

Comment: I downloaded this zip file http://gridwars.marune.de/bin/gridwars_lin.zip , check if in your home directory it works.

Comment: @wilf executable is downloaded as an executable inside a tar.gz, not an installer or a packet.

Comment: I think the "not a dynamic executable" message can result if you run a ldd from a 32-bit system on 64-bit executable (or possibly vice versa, if multiarch support is not available). You can use the `file` command to determine the architecture of the executable e.g. `file gridwars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the following package,

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
sudo apt-get install libxxf86vm1:i386
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa:i386
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386
```

You get

```
moi@somewhere:/opt/gridwars/gridwars_lin$ ldd gridwars 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77b2000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf765d000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0xf7604000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0xf757c000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xf7576000)
    libstdc++.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.5 (0xf74bc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7479000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf745e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf72a9000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf7287000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7282000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0xf726b000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf7259000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf7254000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf724d000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xf724a000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xf7232000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0xf722d000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0xf721f000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7136000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7119000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77b3000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf7115000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf710e000)
```

And the game works.

Answer (score 0):

**How to install Gridwars 2**

Open terminal and run these:

```
mkdir gridwars && cd gridwars
wget http://gridwars.marune.de/bin/gridwars_lin.zip
unzip gridwars_lin.zip
./gridwars
```

I then got this error:

```
[wilf@comp gridwars]$ ./gridwars 
./gridwars: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I had to [install the libstdc 5](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=673762) - I - I [found an rpm](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/19/i386/c/compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-68.7.i686.html) instead so installed that on my Fedora 19 machine.

It then worked very well - nice game [image: smiley]